# Little Book of Semaphores - barrier

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

I'm going through the book mentioned in the topic, and one thing bugs me. For Barrier, the solution is the following (pseudo)code:

```
1 rendezvous
2
3 mutex.wait ()
4     count = count + 1
5 mutex.signal()
6
7 if count == n: barrier.signal ()
8
9  barrier.wait()
10 barrier.signal()
11
12 critical point
```

However, should not the counter's readout be also mutex-protected, so there are no inconsistencies while reading? I mean this:

```
3 mutex.wait ()
4     count = count + 1
5     if count == n: barrier.signal()
6 mutex.signal()
```

Or am I overly cautious about the counter var maybe?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it should be protected, and your fix looks right.

It's possible the author oversimplified their pseudocode, and actually meant this:

```
3 mutex.wait ()
4     count = count + 1
5     c = count
6 mutex.signal()
7 
8 if c == n: barrier.signal ()
```

... which would be correct.